# high chart label outside of view

Tags: highcharts

[image]

I am creating a radar chart with high chart and found that one of the labels, `Thinking` is missing a `T` after rendering.

Is there anyway I can do to avoid that? My expected solution is to shrink the main chart a bit smaller to fit the outside container. But can we do that automatically? because the outside container varies as the browser resizes (some times even on mobile).

Thanks for any kind of tips!

Comment: You might consider submitting this as a bug (on the HighCharts GitHub issue tracker).

Comment: @JohnZwinck I am not sure whether this is a bug until some official guys check out. I encountered some situations and finally figure out those were not bugs.

Comment: Well the official guys are on the bug tracker, they'll tell you if this is not a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set proper width using `min-width` and `max-width` properties of chart `container`. `min-width` should be set so that your whole chart is visible. For example:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 600px; max-width: 700px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

See also [highchart spider example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar-spider/)

Comment: sorry for the late reply after months. I try your demo in fiddle but it seems when the width is very small, there's no room for the text. Actually most cases on mobile there would be not enough space for the text. Is there any new solution for that (like rotate the text)? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, didn't try that. One possibility is smaller font but than readability will suffer.